# DNS gTLD works on REST but not in the browser

Tags: heroku, dns, cname

My DNS Management has been set up properly. I set the Type to `CNAME`, the Name to `www` and the value to the what Heroku gave me. The website is http://chatbubble.app. When I use VS Code REST Client to have a GET request to http://www.chatbubble.app, I get a correct response from my website with a status of 200 OK and I can see my website code. However, when I go to my browser, I cannot access the website. Is it because of the `.app` gTLD?
Also, the browser keeps sending me to the HTTP**S** version of my site. Even when I remove the **s** in `https://` it keeps redirecting me. Can someone help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`.app` is on the HSTS preloading list. Browsers will only do HTTPS requests to website whose name ends in `.app`, they will never do HTTP requests.

This should have been explained to you (Google - registry - requirement on all registrars) when you have registered your `.app` domain name. If your registrar failed to let you know that before registering the domain name, it broke the registry requirements and did not do a good job in helping you use your domain name.

See "Be More Secure" at https://get.app/#benefits or various other questions on StackExchange that deal with `.app`.

Note that the situation (being on HSTS preloading list) is the same for any newer Google TLD. So it is the same for `.dev` and will be the same for `.new` in one month.

Comment: So I still can make HTTP requests to my website but not HTTPS? And also, even though I have SSL, why can't I make HTTPS requests to it?

Comment: If your website is under `.app` browsers will do HTTPS requests only and never HTTP ones. As for the rest, you do not provide enough details on your problem and your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. Have a look at [su], [sf], or [webmasters.se] but read their help section to find out what is more appropriate.